# Email Validation php

Tags: emails, forms

When validating an email address using the code below I get this error when i run the same code from within a drupal node, where I coded a form using php/html

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
$errors[] = 'Please enter valid email';
}
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function filter_var() in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 53
```

Comment: What's your PHP version and Drupal version? [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) exists only in PHP 5.2.0 and later, so it can well not exist if your site is Drupal 6 or earlier.

Comment: You got it in one, I have php 5.2+ but using Drupal 6.

Comment: Actually it *should* be available to you in that case. Problem is - if code of some module prevents it from working it will not be considered a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option might be to use [`valid_email_address()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/valid_email_address/6) to keep it all Drupal friendly :)

> Verifies the syntax of the given e-mail address.

See [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) for details.

Example:

```
if (valid_email_address($email) != TRUE) {
  $errors[] = 'Please enter valid email';
}
```